# error when creating a virtual environment under linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

I entered 'mkvietualenv ssccenv' at the terminal and reported an error.

```
'OSError: Command /root/.virtualenvs/ssccenv/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2'
```

can you tell me why is that-

Comment: what is your ubuntu version, for which python version are you trying to create virtual environment

Comment: i use python 3.5.2 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: i tried to re-install virtualenv but it can not works, now it is tell me a new error '-bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory'

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

**Install pip first (if not installed)**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Then install virtualenv using pip3**

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

**Now create a virtual environment**

```
python3 -m virtualenv /path/to/myenv
```

or

```
virtualenv -p python3 /path/to/myenv
```

The above mentioned steps are for Python 3. Since you are using Python 3, these should work.

Answer (score 0):

try creating virtual env by,

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 ssccenv
```